# Youtube Embedded Video White Areas

Tags: html, css, youtube, youtube-api

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 1000; width: 100%; height: 100%">
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aQsy17K84Ls?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3">
</iframe>
</div>
```

When i use above code, i get white areas on the left and bottom of the screen.
I tried width and height but not works.
How can i make the video absolutely full screen?

Comment: works for me. check in inspector, it is probably getting css from other files. can you share link or fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body of html pushes it. You need to add to your css file;

```
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Or maybe its better to use [Normalise](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Answer (score 0):

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

"How can i make the video absolutely full screen?"

If I understand your question correctly, you want the video to fill up the entire screen like YT's full-screen mode. You can, take a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

If that is not the solution, follow @pacanga's advice.

Hope this helps!